# Writing a function (method) to print out the transaction details

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have displayed the transaction details by using linq query. Now how can I write a function(or method) that takes a Transaction ID as a parameter to print out this transaction details?

```
            var context = new Context();
            var result = (from sale in context.PurchaseHeads
                     join line in context.PurchaseLines on sale equals line.PurchaseHead
                     join staff in context.Staffs on sale.Staff equals staff
                     join store in context.Stores on sale.Store equals store
                     join customer in context.Customers on sale.Customer equals customer
                     join product in context.Products on line.Product equals product
                     group new { line.Quantity, product.Price } by new
                     { sale.ID,
                         StaffName = staff.Name,
                         StoreName = store.Name,
                         CustomerName = customer.Name} into gr
                     select new
                     {
                         TransactionID = gr.Key.ID,
                         StaffName = gr.Key.StaffName,
                         StoreName = gr.Key.StoreName,
                         CustomerName = gr.Key.CustomerName,
                         Total = gr.Sum(x => x.Quantity * x.Price),
                     }).ToList();

 foreach (var item in result)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(item.TransactionID + " " + item.StaffName + " " + item.StoreName + " " + item.CustomerName + " " + item.Total);
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
```

Answer (score 0):

It would probably be not a bad idea to save your result in a Dictionary instead of a list, then you could just do 
`result[<ID>]` to get to the corresponding details.

If you need to keep it a list for whatever reason:

```
result.FirstOrDefault(x => x.TransactionID == <ID>)
```

if there is no entry with the given id it will return null.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the results in the function

```
public void printTransactionDetails(List<ResultClass> result, int transactionId) {
     var transaction = result.FirstOrDefault(x => x.TransactionId == transactionId);

     if (transaction != null) {
         Console.WriteLine(transaction.TransactionID + " " + transaction.StaffName + " " + transaction.StoreName + " " + transaction.CustomerName + " " + item.Total);
     }
}
```

or query the result inside the function

```
public void printTransactionDetails(int transactionId) {
     var context = new Context();
        var result = (from sale in context.PurchaseHeads
                 join line in context.PurchaseLines on sale equals line.PurchaseHead
                 join staff in context.Staffs on sale.Staff equals staff
                 join store in context.Stores on sale.Store equals store
                 join customer in context.Customers on sale.Customer equals customer
                 join product in context.Products on line.Product equals product
                 group new { line.Quantity, product.Price } by new
                 { sale.ID,
                     StaffName = staff.Name,
                     StoreName = store.Name,
                     CustomerName = customer.Name} into gr
                 select new
                 {
                     TransactionID = gr.Key.ID,
                     StaffName = gr.Key.StaffName,
                     StoreName = gr.Key.StoreName,
                     CustomerName = gr.Key.CustomerName,
                     Total = gr.Sum(x => x.Quantity * x.Price),
                 }).FirstOrDefault(c => c.TransactionId == transactionId); 

     if (transaction != null) {
         Console.WriteLine(transaction.TransactionID + " " + transaction.StaffName + " " + transaction.StoreName + " " + transaction.CustomerName + " " + item.Total);
     }
}
```